# Responsive Bootstrap Navigation Bar in Angular

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I do have a bootstrap@3 navigation bar in my Angular 7 project.

```
nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">

        <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">
          <div class="container" style="padding-left: 0px;  padding-right: 0px; height: 20px; width: 40px">
              UTCN
          </div>
          </a>
         <div class="navbar-brand" style="margin-left: 3px;"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></div>
    </div>


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <ng-template [ngIf]="!authService.isAuthenticated()">
          <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/signup">Register</a></li>
          <li routerLinkActive="active"><a routerLink="/signin">Login</a></li>
        </ng-template>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I need to obtain a **responsive** behaviour, but the right side content, the *div* element with class '*nav navbar-nav navbar-right*' is dissapearing when screen size is small (**xs**).

How can i make the that div to use the left-side available space and not vanishing?

Comment: Post the definitions for the css classes 'nav navbar-nav navbar-right'

Comment: Do you have jquery installed? I believe you have to install jquery to get any of the responsive behavior defined in bootstrap.

Comment: Use ng-bootstrap instead of pure vootstrap so you don't need jquery